# Matching numbers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to finish a homework assignment and I can't find this anywhere. I'm trying to match input numbers with randomly generated numbers and displaying how many of the 5 are correct (also with a win/lose message). This is what I have so far and any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //variables
    int lottery[5], user[5];
    int count = 0;
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
    int winnum;
    //generating numbers
    for (int i=0; i <5; i++)
    {
        lottery[i] =1+rand()%9;
    }
    //input
    cout << "Enter a digit between 0-9: ";
    cin >> num1;
    // ...
    cin >> num5;

    winnum = rand();

    //display
    cout << "Winning Lottery Numbers: " << winnum << endl;
    cout << "Your ticket Numbers: " 
         << num1 << num2 << num3 << num4 << num5 << endl;

    //matching the numbers
    //HELP!
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Call `srand (time (NULL))` at the beginning of main to get different lottery numbers each execution. Specific problems you're having is good information.

Comment: Still not really too sure what to do, Sorry I'm a pretty big novice with this.  I'm trying to find out how to create an output saying how many user input numbers match the randomly generated numbers.

Comment: Match in the same position or any position?

Comment: any position.  (15 characters needed)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, just input the elements of `user` instead of creating 5 new variables. Keep a count (remember to initialize it to 0) of how many matches you find. As the user enters each number, you can check to see whether it matches a lottery number. If it does, increase the counter.

A few other things:

- Don't **ever** use `void main()`. Use `int main()` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` instead. The OS expects your program to return something, and with `int main()`, 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS) is returned if no return value is specified in `main`.
- Call `srand (time (NULL));` (include `<ctime>`) at the beginning of your program. This sets the seed to a changing value so that the pseudorandom numbers generated by `rand` won't be the same every time you run your program.
- I'm not really sure what the point of num1-5 and winnum are when you have `user[5]` and `lottery[5]`.
- You can replace `system ("PAUSE")` with

  `cin.sync();`
  `cin.get();`

  which is a lot better than pause and doesn't have the inconsistencies of how many times to press enter as `cin.ignore()` and `cin.get()` alone do.
- You'll have to validate that no two lottery numbers are the same if that's part of the assignment.

Comment: +1 for discouraging the use of `void main()`.  That's a habit that needs to be broken immediately.

Comment: @AlexYan, as I mentioned, C++ automatically returns 0 from `main` if the return statement is not there.